# SSRS - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

OK I've come across something that baffles me.

I've downloaded SSDT for Visual Studio 2017, version 15.5.2

I'm creating new .rdls.  I use Reports --> Add  -->  New Item  for Reports.

Have my DataSource and Dataset created, no problem.  i use an existing stored proc to retrieve, and it's no problem.

But i cant' figure out why there is no DETAIL band.  I mean, any item that is retrieved, is First(columnname) for a string column, or Sum(columnname) for a numeric column, etc.  Why on earth can i not just have a detail row, for all the  columns i select?  Not having a detail band really defeats the purpose of a report in the first place.  I can have a page header/footer for summarizations and such.

So do i need to use the Report Wizard instead?  The wizard does not seem to allow me to select a stored proc, so that seems useless to me as well.

Why is there no Detail band when i create a report?  i thought that was standard when creating a new report, when i used SSRS in the past.

Comment: Please edit your question title to something other than a repetition of the tag information. Your title should describe the specific problem you're having or question you're asking, in a clear way that will be of use to a future reader here who sees it in a list of search results. Redundantly repeating the information you've already provided in the tags is useless. Thanks.

Comment: have you added a table or matrix to the report or are you just creating individual textboxes  on the report? If you add a table or matrix, the detail group will be there by default. If you create an isolated textbox on the report design surface then in the context of the text box the only logical way the report can handle that is to apply some kind of aggregation of (SUM/FIRST/LAST etc)

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you have placed a tablix or a matrix on the design window, Right click on the tablix.. select `Tablix Properties` and then set the `Data set Name` to your actual dataset in that window. You should now be able to select the columns as required.